# How to automatically fill up information on sheet 2 when information is input in sheet 1

Tags: excel

I have a sheet of data whereby if the column is of certain value, it will return the whole row of data in another sheet. Example table as below.

```
PIC Name    Phone number    Gender  Nationality
Ali Sad     123218972       Female  US
Fahril Sam  435262626       Female  US
Abu James   26426426426     Male    US
```

I'm not too sure of the formula to output with the condition of when PIC=Ali, whole row will be returned on sheet 2. Given the extra condition of Ali might have in charged for more than 1 person. Assuming PIC is A1. Result will be as below in sheet 2

```
Name    Phone number    Gender  Nationality
Sad     123218972       Female  US
```

Comment: Looks like all you need is `=Sheet1!A1`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using vlookup, ideally what i wanted was when sheet 1 is filled with data, sheet 2 will be automatically filled with the data, but then it didnt work. Say when there is more than Ali in the table.